# Idiomatic way to get related model list

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a couple of simple models, with an M2M relationship through a model (extra data on relationship removed for clarity):

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    communities = models.ManyToManyField(Community, through='CommunityMembership')

class Community(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

class CommunityMembership(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community)
```

If I want to get all of the communities associated with a team, I know I can first get the ids of the communities through the m2m field and then use that list to filter the Communities:

```
communities = Community.objects.filter(id__in=team.communities.all().values_list('community_id', flat=True)
```

This feels unnecessarily cumbersome and I'd like to learn if there is a more idiomatic way to get just the communities for a team in a single statement without first querying the ids

(pseudocode)

```
communities = team.communities.all().values_list('community') # this returns ths ids of the communities, not the whole Community model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to get all of the communities associated with a team

```
#you just need to use the M2M field
communities = team.communities.all()

#If you want CommunityMemberships instead
community_memberships = team.communitymembership_set.all()
```

Comment: Using the former gets me the CommunityMembership objects; I'm looking for a way to get the Community objects that the CommunityMembership object relates to. With this solution, I still have to iterate through CommunityMemberships to get to the Community object.

Comment: Which one of the two statements? I'm still struggling to understand what's the problem and what exactly do you mean.

Comment: Actually, I think you're right. My confusion comes from trying to treat a 'related_name' back reference (which gives me instances of the through model) and an actual m2m field definition on the model (which gives me instances of the related model). For the question I've asked, this is the correct answer.